# Weights and Biases of LSTM Layer Python

Tags: python, lstm, hyperparameters

I have developed an LSTM Model with 1 LSTM layer and 3 dense layers as shown below

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(units = 120, activation ='relu', return_sequences = False,input_shape 
(train_in.shape[1],5)))
    
model.add(Dense(100,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

I have trained the model and obtained the trained weights and biases of the model. The details are shown below.

```
w = model.get_weights()
w[0].shape, w[1].shape,w[2].shape,w[3].shape,w[4].shape,w[5].shape,w[6].shape,w[7].shape,w[8].shape
```

The output I got is,

```
 ((5, 480),(120, 480),(480,),(120, 100),(100,),(100, 50),(50,),(50, 1),(1,))
```

It has given out 2 weight matrices of dimensions (5,480)&(120,480) and one bias matrix of dim (480,) corresponding to the LSTM layer. the others are related to the dense layers.

The thing I want to know is that, LSTM has 4 layers. So How can I get the weights and biases of these 4 layers separately? Can I divide the total weights(5,480) into 4 equal parts and consider the 1st 120 correspond to the 1st layer of LSTM, 2nd 120 belong to the 2nd layer of LSTM and so on??

Please share your valuable thoughts on this. Also any good references please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An LSTM doesn't have 4 *layers* but *4 weight matrices* due to its internal gate-cell structure. If this is confusing, it is helpful to read some resources on how an LSTM works. To summarize, the internals consist of 3 gates and 1 cell state which are used to calculate the final hidden state.

If you check the [underlying implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent_v2.py#L1382), you can see in which order they are concatenated:

```
[i, f, c, o]

# i is input gate weights (W_i).
# f is forget gate weights (W_f).
# o is output gate weights (W_o).
# c is cell gate weights (W_c).
```

So on the example of your bias tensor `(480,)`, you can divide this into 4 subtensors with size 120, where `w[:120]` represents the input gate weights, `w[120:240]` represents the forget gate weights and so on.

Comment: Hello @runSOSrun, thank you for your response. I have gone through the underlying implementation. I got a better understanding of the process. But I have 2 major doubts here which I could not figure out. My input has 5 variables each of 20  time steps length, the size of my inputs would be (5*20), but the size of the weights for the input gate is (5*120). The size doesnt match and hence cannot  be multiplied. Also what should be the size and value of my initial hidden state 'h' ?? Please let me know how to move forward with this.

Comment: `return_sequences = False` returns the final timestep as a hidden state, `True` keeps the temporal dimension intact. So the sizes do match internally when unrolled. Your last question is really impossible to answer comprehensively in 2 sentences so you might want to read more sources. As a beginner, don't worry about initialization. The size of `h` is 120 in your case. If you mean "what is the ideal size?": this is always model- and data-dependent. you always run a gridsearch to find out the best value experimentally by training multiple networks (called hyperparameter optimization).

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and helping me out :)